# delphi assign condition to object property

Tags: delphi, conditional-statements

I want to write this piece of code in more beautiful way

```
if some_condition then
  checkbox.Checked := true
else
  checkbox.Checked := false;
```

I want something like

```
checkbox.checked := boolean_value_of_condition_is_met;
```

Comment: check this out http://stevepeacocke.blogspot.hr/2007/08/have-iif-function-in-delphi.html

Comment: It seems you know the answer.

Comment: The short and simple form is `CheckBox.Checked := some_condition;`. No `if`-clause needed.

Comment: upvoted just because you want to improve your code.

Answer (score 8):

You can indeed write the code exactly as you imagine. For instance, using a boolean expression like this:

```
CheckBox.Checked := SomeValue = 42;
CheckBox.Checked := SomeValue > 0;
CheckBox.Checked := SomeBoolean;
CheckBox2.Checked := not CheckBox1.Checked;
```

or by calling a function that returns a boolean like this:

```
function GetSomeBooleanValue(Value: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := ...;
end;

...

CheckBox.Checked := GetSomeBooleanValue(42);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just write

```
checkbox.Checked := some_condition;
```

some_condition is, by definition a Boolean, and so can be assigned to checkbox.checked.